# javax.ws.rs.core.Response with a collection as entity

Tags: java, rest, arraylist, jax-rs, response

I have the following code:

```java
    @GET
    @Path("v1/entity")
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "List",
            notes = "Enables you to List.",
            tags = { "List" })
    @ApiImplicitParams(
            {
                @ApiImplicitParam(name = "pageSize",
                    value = "Page Size",
                    dataType = "int",
                    paramType = "formData",
                    example = "50"),
                @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sortAscending",
                    value = "Sort Ascending",
                    dataType = "boolean",
                    paramType = "formData",
                    example = "false")
            })
    public Response list(@ApiParam(hidden = true) Integer pageSize,
            @ApiParam(hidden = true) Boolean sortAscending) {
        Collection<EntityData> dataCollection;
        if (pageSize == null || sortAscending == null || pageSize <= 0) {
            dataCollection = storeController.list();
        } else {
            SortDirection sortDirection = sortAscending ? SortDirection.ASC : SortDirection.DESC;
            dataCollection= storeController.list(pageSize, sortDirection);
        }
        logger.info("List contains {} elements", dataCollection.size());
        GenericEntity<Collection<EntityData>> response = new GenericEntity<Collection<EntityData>>(dataCollection){};
        return Response.ok(response).build();
        //return ResponseEntity.ok(dataCollection);
    }
```

Both methods from `storeController` object only return an `ArrayList` of EntityData, whose structure is below:

```java
public class EntityData implements Serializable {

    private String document;

    private String validTo;

    private String validFrom;

    private String entityAlias;

    public String getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(String document) {
        this.document= document;
    }

    public String getValidTo() {
        return validTo;
    }

    public void setValidTo(String validTo) {
        this.validTo = validTo;
    }

    public String getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    public void setValidFrom(String validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }

    public String getEntityAlias() {
        return entityAlias;
    }

    public void setEntityAlias(String entityAlias) {
        this.entityAlias = entityAlias;
    }
}
```

When I call the API, I get this error:

```
No message body writer has been found for class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType: */*
```

I used [this as a reference](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_returning_a_list), but it didn't work. I've also tried to, instead of using `Response` to retrieve the contents, using `ResponseEntity<Collection<EntityData>>`, but the error persists. Just as using directly the "`ArrayList`" in the `Response` (without wrapping on `GenericEntity`).

If I change the last line to `return Response.ok().build();` it works, but I need the `Collection` to be retrieved... The `logger` indicates that the Collection has 9 elements when I run.

I know I am missing something here, but I can't see it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your resource method (or the entire resource class) is annotated either with:

- `@Produces("applicaton/json")` or;
- `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Then ensure you have a JSON provider, such as Jackson, in the classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Depending on how the JAX-RS implementation is configured, adding the [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers) artifact to your classpath is enough to use Jackson as a JSON provider. Otherwise you need to register [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html).

Comment: I'm already using this dependency on my pom.xml (version `<version>2.9.6</version>`). It isn't working yet... Is there another newer version I should use?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I've just read your question again. Looks like you are producing `*/`, as the `@Produces` annotation is missing. So add `@Produces("application/json")` to your method or to your class.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Just edited your answer to add your last comment there - the actual solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
// it is part of jerssy Glassfish
// when we have retuen type List<object>
// what is repsosne we return.
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

public List<EmpDTO>  smaple test()
{
        Response getempresposne = null;
List<EmpDTO> getemplist = new ArrayList<>();
         getemplist = getempresposne.readEntity(new GenericType<List<EmpDTO>>() {});

}
```

Comment: I honestly didn't understand a single thing you tried to do there. Is it related to my (old and already answered) question at all?